# A usage about Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

i have a question about a weird usage of Perl regex.
Code is here:

> ```
> $pattern = "some_pattern";  
> while (<FH>)  
> {
>     if (m/^\s*{\s*$pattern\s*,/ .. /^[^%]*}\./)
>     {    
>          ## blablabla
>     }    
> }
> ```

The contents in filehandle(FH) is something like:

> ```
> {mns_host, 'dls2304-1', 1, 8}.    % ConTest
> {mns_host, 'dls2304-2', 2, 10}.   % ConTest
>
> {gn_c_ip_addresses, 1, '10.138.97.96', 27, undefined, 0}.    % ConTest
> {gn_c_ip_addresses, 2, '10.138.99.32', 27, undefined, 0}.    % ConTest
>
> {gn_router_list, false, ['10.136.64.98']}.  % ConTest
> ```

i am confused with the expression: `m/^\s*{\s*$pattern\s*,/ .. /^[^%]*}\./`, especially the usage of `/ .. /`, what does this express mean?
Can you help me?　
Thank you in advance

Brs,
Ruan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `..`, in scalar context (as used in your example code) is a flip-flop operator.  [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) says this:

> In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. The operator is
>   bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma)
>   operator of sed, awk, and various editors. Each ".." operator
>   maintains its own boolean state, even across calls to a subroutine
>   that contains it. It is false as long as its left operand is false.
>   Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the
>   right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false
>   again.

In your usage, once the regex on the left matches, the flip flop operator flips to true, and your `if()` statement becomes true.  It remains true on each iteration until after the regexp on the right matches.  Then it flops to false, and stays that way until the regexp on the left matches again in some future iteration.

Answer (score 2):

No, the regex ends before the `/`. There are three operators in question

- Match operator #1: `m/^\s*{\s*$pattern\s*,/`
- Match operator #2: `/^[^%]*}\./`
- And both are operands to the flip-flop operator, `EXPR .. EXPR`.

The flip-flop operator returns false as long as its LHS returns false. Once its LHS returns true, the flip-flop returns true as long as its RHS returns true.

[perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `..` is the range operator. From the [Perl docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators):

> In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. The operator is bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma) operator of sed, awk, and various editors. Each ".." operator maintains its own boolean state, even across calls to a subroutine that contains it. It is false as long as its left operand is false. Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false again.

In this case, the two arguments to the range operator are the two match regexes.

```
m/^\s*{\s*$pattern\s*,/
```

and

```
/^[^%]*}\./
```